# Non-blocking raw_input with line editing using gevent

Tags: python, python-2.7, io, gevent

I'm trying to implement an interactive shell over an internal API which uses gevent. I want the background greenlets to continue running while waiting on user input, and I also want readline command-line functionality (history, line editing, etc.)

My problem seems to be that raw_input is blocking. There are solutions around which replace raw_input with things like:

```
def raw_input(prompt):
  sys.stdout.write(prompt)
  sys.stdout.flush()

  select.select([sys.stdin], [], [])
  return sys.stdin.readline().rstrip('\n')
```

This solves the blocking problem; the background greenlets now run fine. But I lose the interactive line-editing functionality.

Any suggestions or workarounds?

Comment: I don't have a solid answer, but a couple of nudges in hopefully a correct direction: Have you tried the `cmd` module? Or, have you tried to incorporate the `readline` module into your redefinition of `raw_input()`? I'm not optimistic about the latter case, since the `readline` module feels pretty crippled compared to the actual C library, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Well, cmd looked promising, but by default it uses raw_input, so it blocks. You can set use_rawinput to false, but not only does it still block, but you lose the line editing as well!

Answer (score 2):

You could try using raw_input in a seprecate thread and then returning the result to a global variable. Not sure if this would work for you, it worked for me but in an entirely different scenario